# How to export all the files in Source Control to a separate folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have approx 200 files in my project waiting to be committed to Git, but I'd like to export them to a local folder first, and have just those edited files in one place. How could I achieve this?

Comment: I'd get the list of files from `git status`, and copy them with a shell script. But why would you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: Well to be honest - the reason I'm doing it is because I'm working on a hobby project site (built by Jekyll theme) and I'd like to have two separate sites on two separate URLs, but they'll be 95% identical (some image and text changes between the two) so I don't know how to do it other than deploy the first site and then use all the edited scss and md files from that local folder to apply on the second site. I'll do it by using Github repo and Netlify to deploy the two sites.

Comment: You should make two branches, with and without the changes. When deploying, can you specify the branch?

Comment: I just started using these tools, and I don't want to screw something up, in VSCode I have options to create new branch, and new branch from...don't want to mess something up - that's why I'd like to somehow export only the edited files in a safe folder, while I'm learning :D

Comment: I'd backup the whole folder, and start messing with the branches. Sounds like a good opportunity to me.

Comment: I'l do that - the only reason why I was hesitant with backing the folder up because I'm not knowledgeable on how the site actually works. My perspective comes from old way of doing things, dropping files in "public html" folder and you load up index file and there's your site. But this process (uploading to Github repo, deploying on Netlify) makes me thing that there's more to these files than what I have locally, maybe Netlify does something when deploying hence a mere drag and drop of files in Github repo on a site that's already deployed isn't a correct way...but I'm probably wrong